# How to use php to generate random 10 digit number that begins with the same two digits

Tags: php, random, numbers

I'm working on a banking and investment website/system for my school project, please can someone help me with a PHP code that generates a random 10 digits account number when users register, but the account numbers all have to start with the same two-digit numbers like 01, thank you

Comment: Generate 8 digit number, make first two fixed. An answer is actually in your question). If you are having troble with code, then post the code, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Before asking for a solution right now without even posting code, please at least try to code something :) StackOverflow is about helping people solving problems, not doing their work instead of them. I'm pretty sure there are plenty of examples if you use your favorite search engine!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
$fixed = '01';
$number = $fixed.mt_rand( 10000000, 99999999);
echo $number;
```